# Storing Excel templates in my Access database

Tags: windows, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

## What I want:

I am working with an MS Access database to produce a report for the Ontario Professional Engineering University Accreditation board. The PEO have their templates in MS Excel and I MUST use their exact format.

I want to output the data from the Access DB to the Excel sheet (easy enough), but I want to copy their formatting when producing a new file. (I do NOT want to keep an empty template file and copy it each time).

So essentially I'm looking to somehow store the template in code. (Other suggestions are welcome!)

## What I've tried:

Some of you will read this and think i'm an idiot. But what i tried was to get the data from excel on the MS Clipboard through the [API Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194373%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and store the DataObject as (i was hoping) some sort of string.

But i could not preserve the formatting or cell shading from the original MS Excel template.

Any suggestions?...

Comment: What version of Access are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could store the Excel template(s) within the database by creating a table that includes an `Attachment` field

[image: DesignView.png]

creating a record and saving the Excel template as an attachment to that record

[image: AttachmentsDialog.png]

and then using VBA code like this to save a new copy of the Excel document to disk whenever you need one:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub SaveReportTemplateToFile()
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rowRst As DAO.Recordset, attachRst As DAO.Recordset2, attachField As DAO.Field2
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    Set rowRst = cdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT TemplateFile FROM ReportTemplates WHERE ID=1")
    Set attachRst = rowRst.Fields("TemplateFile").Value
    Set attachField = attachRst.Fields("FileData")
    attachField.SaveToFile "C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\" & attachRst.Fields("FileName").Value
    Set attachField = Nothing
    attachRst.Close
    Set attachRst = Nothing
    rowRst.Close
    Set rowRst = Nothing
    Set cdb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks FANTASTIC! So storing an attachment in a table means the DB has a hard copy? So i do not need to keep the .xls file with the Access DB?

Comment: @user3163380 Yes, the attachment file is saved as an object within the database.

Comment: Thank you this is a great answer to my problem! And thank you for the screenshot images they were EXTREMELY helpful

Comment: Gord, you have just made my life a hell of a lot easier! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you are going to have to do is first export all the data into a new sheet of an empty template, then link all the data to the correct place on the template and then remove the sheet with all the data, keeping the data on the template.

As far as I know there is no quicker way to do this, but here is an example: http://www.rogersaccesslibrary.com/forum/topic350.html

It will be quite a job, but doable, if the template is well setup.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as i mentioned; I want to somehow avoid keeping the Excel template all together.

I would like to replicate the templates format programatically, that way if i move the Access DB i do not have to keep it tied with an external Excel file.

(Also this will avoid the song-and-dance of copying into a new sheet of an empty template then linking to the other sheet)

Comment: Why not store the template in the Access DB ?  Replicating the template entirely via code seems like a lot of work for no obvious benefit.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, I did not know you could do this. I accepted this as the best answer (from Gord T). Thank you for the suggestion!